# Making a generic mode function in C

Tags: c, generics, void-pointers

*So I've been trying to make a generic function that calculates the (mathematical) mode of some type. 
I've got part of it down but am missing other parts, so it won't compile. I need help on how to fill in those missing parts.*

The mode function for integers uses a `struct count` to determine the element and frequency. Its definition is:

```
struct count {
    int value;          // the value of the number
    unsigned int freq;  // how many times the number has been seen
}
```

The integer version of mode outputs an array that contains all the ties for the most frequent number along with how many ties there are.

```
unsigned int mode(int* tiebuf, int* list, size_t listsize)
{
    struct count modelist[listsize];
    size_t modesize = 0;

    // initialize modelist[]
    for(int i = 0; i < listsize; i++)
    {
        int* found = search(list[i], modelist, modesize);    // signature: search(key, list, listsize)
        if(found == NULL)
        {
            (modelist[i]).num = &list[i];
            (modelist[i]).freq = 0;
             modesize++;
        }
        else
        {
            (*found).freq++;
        }
    }

    // take the most frequent element (last in modelist)
    qsort(modelist, listsize, sizeof(struct count), cmpfreq);
    int mode_element = listsize-1;

    // see if there are any ties for frequency
    size_t tiecount = 1;
    for(int i = mode_element-1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        if((modelist[i]).freq < (modelist[mode_element]).freq)
        {
            tiecount++;    // overshot by 1
            break;
        }
    }

    // output the tie as an array
    for(int i = 0; i < tiecount; i++)
    {
        tiebuf[i] = (modelist[mode_element-1-i].number);
    }
    return tiecount;    // returns how many elements are in tiebuf
}


int cmpfreq(const void* obj1, const void* obj2)
{
    struct count **t1 = (struct count**)obj1;
    struct count **t2 = (struct count**)obj2;
    return ( ((*t1)->freq) - ((*t2)->freq) );
}


int cmpnum(const void* obj1, const void* obj2)
{
    struct count **t1 = (struct count**)obj1;
    struct count **t2 = (struct count**)obj2;
    return ( ((*t1)->number) - ((*t2)->number) );
}


int* tiedmode( int* list, size_t listsize, int (*cmp)(const void*, const void*) )
{
    // takes the median of all ties in the mode
    int ties[listsize];
    int tiescount = mode(ties, list, listsize);
    qsort(ties, tiescount, cmpnum);    // this call doesn't work
                                       // want to call cmpnum with cmp as an argument
                                       // this is why we needed cmpnum
    int middle = tiescount/2;
    return ties[middle];
}
```

Now I plan on converting this to a generic notation. The first thing to do is change the definition of
`struct count`

```
struct count {
    void* object;       // some object
    unsigned int freq;  // how many times that object has appeared
}
```

The signature for mode must also change to 
`unsigned int mode(void* tiebuf, size_t tienum, void* list, size_t listsize, size_t objsize, int (*cmp)(const void*, const void*))`

The big problem is with the auxiliary function `cmpnum` and this is where I have trouble. Since `qsort` requires a function pointer with the signature `int (*fnptr)(const void*, const void*)`, `cmpnum` also requires that signature. However to compare objects, `cmpnum` probably also needs another function pointer given by the user on how to compare them. Ideally, the `cmpnum` function would look like

```
int cmpnum(const void* obj1, const void* obj2, int (*compare)(const void*, const void*))
{
    struct count** t1 = (struct count**)obj1;
    struct count** t2 = (struct count**)obj2;
    return ( compare(t1->object, t2->object) );
}
```

So how would I cast a function pointer with 3 arguments to a function pointer with only 2 arguments? Or better yet, how would I solve the problem with the discrepancy between* `qsort` and `cmpnum` ?

**EDIT:**  The reason why I need `cmpnum` in the first place is because of `tiedmode`. This function takes the mode and outputs the median of the ties. In order to find the median, I have to sort by number. But since this will be made generic, I need the user to let the library know how to sort the object inside `struct count`.

Comment: "cmpnum probably also needs another function pointer given by the user" you just drop cmpnum entirely and use the user function directly.

Comment: But then the use must know about the structure of `struct count`. I want `struct count` to be completely hidden to the user.

Comment: Sorry didn't read the code too carefully. Didn't see you are sorting an array of struct count. You don't need this. It is easier to sort the original array (or a copy thereof) and then count streaks of identical elements.

Comment: Wait, why do you need cmpnum again? You are sorting with cmpnum and then immediately with cmpfreq, which renders the previous sort completely useless.

Comment: Ah yes. This problem came from a different problem which I tried to generalize. I'll try to look back and find the reason why I needed `cmpnum`. There was *definitely* a reason.

Comment: I added the reason for `cmpnum`.

Comment: `tiedmode` sorts integers (or users' data), not `struct count`, so it isn't clear how `cmpnum` would work there. You also call `qsort` with 3 arguments, which would not compile. `cmpnum` would also not compile as shown because `t1`, `t2` are not pointers to struct, so `->` is not a valid operator for them.

Answer (score 0):

The comparison function you pass to `qsort` can *only* take two arguments.

This is what you do in your top code block.

To do what you want as in your second code block, you'd need to create as many variants of `cmpnum` as you would have `*compare` pointers. (e.g. `cmpnum_type1`, `cmpnum_type2`, etc.) That's the "clean" way.

Another way [which is slightly messy], is to use your original `cmpnum`, but have the `compare` sub-function pointer be a *global*:

```
int (*compare) (const void *, const void *);

int
cmpnum(const void *obj1, const void *obj2)
{
    struct count **t1 = (struct count **) obj1;
    struct count **t2 = (struct count **) obj2;

    return (compare(t1->object, t2->object));
}

void
dosort(void)
{

    compare = foocmp;
    qsort(modelist, listsize, sizeof(struct count), cmpnum);

    compare = barcmp;
    qsort(modelist, listsize, sizeof(struct count), cmpnum);
}
```